# Entered text not getting written into a file in java

Tags: java

```
String str;
String path = "E:/progs/a.txt";

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(path);

while(true)
{
    System.out.print("Enter the words : ");
    str = br.readLine();
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
        break;
    else
        pw.println(str);
}
```

the text that is input by me is not getting written into the file name a.txt specified in the path....may i know the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't close `PrintWriter`. Use `pw.close();`.

always make sure u close a file when you are opening it.

and its a better way to use

```
finally
```

so that u can close all the opened files in the end..

eg:

```
finally
```

`{`
    pw.close();
    }

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your PrintWriter and also consider using braces for your if-else .

```
   else {
    pw.println(str);
    pw.close();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush your data to file

```
else {
pw.println(str);
pw.flush();
pw.close();
```

}

Comment: not really close() would call flush implicitly

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR indeed,but it would make program more readable.